# Strapi mongodb project specific fields in embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, strapi

I'm trying to select especific fields from this document

```
  {
    _id: 60d9295db34f1c0144c9b8d4,
    title: 'Este es el titulo',
    slug: 'este-es-el-titulo',
    date: '2021-06-27',
    category: {
      _id: 60d92921b34f1c0144c9b8d2,
      title: 'Categoria 1',
      slug: 'categoria-1',
      id: '60d92921b34f1c0144c9b8d2'
     },
   cover: {
     _id: 60d72c815e57e6015e38a4c7,
     name: 'project4.png',
     alternativeText: '',
     caption: '',
     hash: 'project4_3e8c906bdf',
     ext: '.png',
     mime: 'image/png',
     size: 540.02,
     width: 1895,
     height: 883,
     url: '/uploads/project4_3e8c906bdf.png',
     formats: [Object],
     provider: 'local',
     related: [Array],
     createdAt: 2021-06-26T13:32:49.389Z,
     updatedAt: 2021-06-28T01:43:57.469Z,
     __v: 0,
     created_by: '60d69246c6f06d00f64312b0',
     updated_by: '60d69246c6f06d00f64312b0',
     id: '60d72c815e57e6015e38a4c7'
   },
    id: '60d9295db34f1c0144c9b8d4'
  }
```

and I want get something like this:

```
      {
    _id: 60d9295db34f1c0144c9b8d4,
    title: 'Este es el titulo',
    slug: 'este-es-el-titulo',
    date: '2021-06-27',
    category: {
      _id: 60d92921b34f1c0144c9b8d2,
      title: 'Categoria 1',
      slug: 'categoria-1',
      id: '60d92921b34f1c0144c9b8d2'
     },
    cover: { url: '/uploads/project4_3e8c906bdf.png'}
    id: '60d9295db34f1c0144c9b8d4'
  }
```

I'm using Strapi with Mongodb and y was trying with the following code:

```
    const requiredData = {
      title: 1,
      slug: 1,
      date: 1,
      category: 1,
      cover: { url: 1 }
     }

     const populateData = [
       {
         path: 'category',
         select: ['title', 'slug']
       }
     ]

     let editorsPick = await strapi.query('posts')
      .model.find({ editorsPick: true}, requiredData)
      .limit(3)
      .populate(populateData)
```

But I only have this:

```
      {
      _id: 60d9295db34f1c0144c9b8d4,
      title: 'Este es el titulo',
      slug: 'este-es-el-titulo',
      date: '2021-06-27',
      category: {
      _id: 60d92921b34f1c0144c9b8d2,
      title: 'Categoria 1',
      slug: 'categoria-1',
      id: '60d92921b34f1c0144c9b8d2'
     },
    id: '60d9295db34f1c0144c9b8d4'
   }
```

(Without cover image), and then try with:

```
    let editorsPick = await strapi.query('posts')
      .model.aggregate([
      {"$match": { editorsPick: true}},
      {"$project": requiredData}
    ])
```

But I got an empty array []

Please I need a little help, and sorry for my english